# Get events from Controller to Full calendar via json and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, calendar

I am working on a calendar module and I can't get events to be loaded to full calendar from the controller. Here's my code.

here's the controller class:

```
public JsonResult PublicHolidayList()
        {
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            events.Add(new Event()
            {

                EventName = "EventName 1",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
                EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
            });
            events.Add(new Event()
            {

                EventName = "EventName 2",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
                EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
            });
            events.Add(new Event()
            {

                EventName = "EventName 3",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
                EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(11).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
            });
            events.Add(new Event()
            {

                EventName = "EventName 4",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(22).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
                EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(25).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
            });
            return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is the script:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: "{}",
        url: "/Leave/PublicHolidayList",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#calendar_ph').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },

                defaultView: 'month',
                editable: true,
                events: data,
                height: 650
            });

        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });


    })
    .done(function (data) {


    });
```

Can someone kindly explain why events are not showing in my calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I faced this problem before and solved with below technique. So just try this

**You need to add moment.js which might fall necessary here**

```
events: $.map(data, function (item, i) {
            var event = new Object();
            event.title = item.EventName;
            event.start = moment(item.StartDate).utc();
            event.end = moment(item.EndDate).utc();
            return event;
})
```

For more detailed description visit

**[why globalization in web.config makes fullcalendar not to render events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556711/why-globalization-in-web-config-makes-fullcalendar-not-to-render-events)**

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding..:)